# Time dependent delay differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

The command NDSolve is really good at solving delay differential equations.
$$x'(t)=x(t)(1-x(t-d))$$

```
d := 1.4;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t - d]), x[t /; t <= 0] == 1.5}, x, {t, -d, 60}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. {sol}], {t, -r, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However, it seems NDSolve cannot solve a delay differential equation with a time dependent delay,
$$x'(t)=x(t)(1-x(t-d(t)))$$

```
ClearAll[d];
d[t_] := 2 + Sin[t];
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t - d[t]]),x[t /; t <= 0] == 1.5}, x, {t, -1, 60}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t] /. {sol}], {t, -r, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Is their a way to solve this kind of differential equations?**

Comment: I guess, you should introduce the initial condition for `d[t]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited for clarity and improved accuracy.**

Here is a simple solution, which perhaps can be improved.  First, replace `x[t]` by `Exp[y[t]]`, to obtain

```
y'[t] == 1 - Exp[y[t - d[t]]]
```

which guarantees that `x[t] > 0` after discretization, and also is a bit simpler to discretize.  Then, the natural discretization would be

```
f = 1/2 + (dl + a*Sin[(n - 1/2) dt])/dt
y[n] = y[n - 1] + (1 - Exp[y[n - f]]) dt
```

except that `f` is not an integer.  Hence, interpolation is needed.  For instance,

```
Clear[y]; dl = 2.; tl = 60; dt = 1/400; y0 = Log[1.5]; a = 0.;
Table[y[n] = y0, {n, -3/dt, 0}];
y[n_] := y[n] = (f = 1/2 + (dl + a*Sin[(n - 1/2) dt])/dt; y[n - 1] + 
    (1 - Exp[y[n - Floor[f]] (1 - Mod[f, 1]) + y[n - Ceiling[f]] Mod[f, 1]]) dt);
ListPlot[Table[Exp[y[n]], {n, 0, tl/dt}], PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, 
    DataRange -> tl, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

which is the same result as

```
NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t - 2]), x[t /; t <= 0] == 1.5}, x[t], {t, 0, 60}];
Plot[%, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

as desired.  Note that we chose a delay of `2.0` rather than `1.4` in the Question, because `2.0` is the average value of `d`.  Now set

```
Clear[y]; dl = 2.; tl = 200; dt = 1/1000; y0 = Log[1.5]; a = 1.;
```

to reflect the sinusoidal variation in `d`.  In addition, using a smaller time step is helpful for good accuracy, and a longer domain is desirable to show variations in the solution pattern.  The result is

[image]

The irregularity is not necessarily surprising, and probably represents beating between the oscillations shown in the first plot and those in `d`.  It also is possible that the solution is mildly chaotic.

Comment: I get different results with your code and an error `General::munfl`.  Maybe there's a typo in there somewhere?

Comment: @ChrisK  Thanks for catching the typo, now fixed.

Answer (score 5):

A faster and more straightforward approach is to use `NDSolve` as follows.  Begin by noting that the first segment of the solution can be computed by

```
xd[t_?NumericQ] := 1.5;
s1 = NDSolve[[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - xd[t]), x[0] == 1.5}, x[t], {t, 0, t1] // Values;
```

where `t1 - (2 + Sin[t1]) == 0`.  With `s1` determined, it becomes possible to compute the next section with

```
xd[t_?NumericQ] := s1[[0]][t - (2 + Sin[t])]
```

and integrating from `t1` to `t2`, where `t2 - (2 + Sin[t2]) == t1`.  In all, 109 steps are required to reach `t = 200`, calculated by

```
step = Rest@NestList[t /. FindRoot[t - (2 + Sin[t]) == #, {t, Max[#, 2]}] &, 0, 109]
(* {2.5542, 3.88062, 4.89775, 7.89684, ..., 196.712, 198.321, 199.334, 202.268} *)
```

Of course, executing `NDSolve` 109 times is both slow and cumbersome, requiring that the 109 solution segments be spliced together.  Using [NDSolve Components](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html), however, simplifies the computation greatly.  It is initialized with

```
xd[t_?NumericQ] := 1.5;
ndss = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - xd[t]), x[0] == 1.5}, x[t], t]];
NDSolve`Iterate[ndss, step[[1]]];
s = First@NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndss] // Values;
xd[t_?NumericQ] := s[[0]][t - (2 + Sin[t])]
```

and completed by iterating through the remaining values of `step`

```
Do[NDSolve`Iterate[ndss, step[[i]]];
   s = First@NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndss] // Values;, {i, 2, 109}]
```

The iteration requires about 1/40 the time and 1/50 the memory of the approach used to obtain the second plot in my earlier answer.  Plotting the final expression for `s` in `Red` and overlaying it on that second plot yields.

[image]

Agreement is excellent except at the tips of some of the highest peaks in the curve.  Perhaps, this is due to the higher order interpolation used by `NDSolve`.   (The earlier answer employs linear interpolation.)  The key observation is that the two solutions do not drift apart as `t` increases.

The method described here should generalize to most ODEs with time-varying delays, provided that the minimum size of `step` elements is not too small.