# How can I draw a phase portrait of a 3-dimensional time-delayed differential equation system?

Tags: differential-equations

LaTeX

$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{V}(t)&=m_1 E(t)+m_2 K(t)-a V^2(t) \\
\dot{E}(t)&=r(\bar{P}-E(t))-b V(t-\tau)+c \eta V(t-\tau) \\
\dot{K}(t)&=(1-\eta) V(t-\tau)-\delta K(t)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $m_1, m_2, a, b, c, \eta, \delta, \bar{P}, \tau$ strictly positive constants, while $0 \leqslant \eta<1$ and $0<r<1$.

I want to solve numerically the above system of delay differential equations in Wolfram Mathematica. How can ı do that ?

WolframAlpha

```
η = 0.75;
δ = 0.1;
τ = 25.4;
m1 = 5;
m2 = 0.0001;
a = 0.1;
b = 0.85;
P = 25;
c = 1;
r = 0.1;
sol = NDSolve[{
    x'[t] == m1*y[t] + m2*z[t] - a*x^2[t], x[t /; t <= 0] == 1.5,
    y'[t] == r*(P - y[t]) - b*x[t - τ] + c*η*x[t - τ], 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == 0.5,
    z'[t] == (1 - η)*x[t - d] - δ*z[t], z[t /; t <= 0] == 1
     }, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 40}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 40}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

I tried to write it this way.

Comment: Try first just searching "delay differential equations" in the search window above.  Study the threads.  For example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226079/time-dependent-delay-differential-equation   Code that example as written in a notebook and run it.  Then study the coupled example in the search list.  Code that one as well, then finally attempt to code yours and if problems, cut and paste the code in your thread and ask help for the specific problem encountered if any.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. But I have already examined the title and solution suggestions you mentioned. Since the system I am researching is 3-dimensional and each of the ODEs depends on the variables in the others, I get an error even though I have made the necessary definitions. And I can't fix it. I have already acted similarly to the title you posted.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! First, it is recommended you retype equations in $\LaTeX$ instead of posting them as image. Second, if you have already tried coding your problem, please include the code you used and any potential errors you get from it. It is easier to provide help in this way.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for the advice. This is what I'm trying to do in its final form.

Comment: Some issues: "Draw a phase portrait" and "solve [a particular] system" mean different things -- which do you want? Syntax: `x[t]^2`. not `x^2[t]`. Undefined: `d` (maybe should be tau?).

Comment: Yes, I realized my mistake. I want to draw a phase portrait. I want to draw the phase ports showing the variation of V, E, and K concerning time. t-V, t-E, t-K and V(t)-E(t)-K(t).

Answer (score 4):

A "phase portrait" for a nonautonomous system is ambiguous. On the one hand, it is often a portrait in state space (in which the state variables determine the state of the system, which would include time, if nonautonomous). On the other hand, typically in DDEs, it seems, what is meant is to plot trajectories of the independent variables, which is I will do.

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
    x'[t] == m1*y[t] + m2*z[t] - a*x[t]^2, x[t /; t <= 0] == x0,
    y'[t] == r*(P - y[t]) - b*x[t - \[Tau]] + c*\[Eta]*x[t - \[Tau]], 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == y0,
    z'[t] == (1 - \[Eta])*x[t - \[Tau]] - \[Delta]*z[t], 
    z[t /; t <= 0] == z0}
   , {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, {x0, y0, z0}];

(* initial condition-histories *)
icPts1 = (10 (1 + SpherePoints[30]));
icPts2 = (5 (2 + SpherePoints[20]));
icPts = Join[icPts1, icPts2];

(* a region for morphing by the flow *)
parametricGC = DeleteCases[
    Show[ConvexHullMesh[icPts1], ConvexHullMesh[icPts2]],
    HoldPattern[VertexNormals -> _],
    Infinity] /. 
   GraphicsComplex[p_, rest__] :> 
    GraphicsComplex[psol @@@ p, {Opacity[0.2], rest}];

Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[psol @@@ icPts // Evaluate
  , {t, 0, 40}
  , PlotStyle -> Thin],
 Table[parametricGC, {t, 0, 40, 20}]
 ]
```

[image]

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[psol @@@ icPts // Evaluate
  , {t, 0, 40}
  , PlotStyle -> Thin, AxesLabel -> {V, Style["E", Italic], K}],
 Table[parametricGC, {t, (4^Range[0, 4] - 1)*40/(4^4 - 1)}]
 ]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 With[{pplot = ParametricPlot3D[
      psol @@@ icPts // Evaluate
      , {t, 0, 40}
      , PlotStyle -> Thin]},
  Dynamic@Show[
    pplot,
    Block[{t = t0}, parametricGC],
    Axes -> True, Boxed -> True, PlotLabel -> t == t0]
  ],
 {t0, 0, 40}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`x^2[t]` should be `x[t]^2` and `x[t - d]` should be `x[t - τ]`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
η = 0.75;
δ = 0.1;
τ = 25.4;
m1 = 5;
m2 = 0.0001;
a = 0.1;
b = 0.85;
P = 25;
c = 1;
r = 0.1;
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == m1*y[t] + m2*z[t] - a*x[t]^2, 
    x[t /; t <= 0] == 1.5, 
    y'[t] == r*(P - y[t]) - b*x[t - τ] + c*η*x[t - τ], 
    y[t /; t <= 0] == 0.5, 
    z'[t] == (1 - η)*x[t - τ] - δ*z[t], 
    z[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 40}];
{v[t_], e[t_], 
   k[t_]} := {Piecewise[{{x[t] /. sol // First, 0 <= t <= 40}, {1.5, 
      t <= 0}}], 
   Piecewise[{{y[t] /. sol // First, 0 <= t <= 40}, {0.5, t <= 0}}], 
   Piecewise[{{z[t] /. sol // First, 0 <= t <= 40}, {1, t <= 0}}]};
Plot[{v[t], e[t], k[t]}, {t, -10, 40}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
(* ParametricPlot3D[{{v[t],e[t],k[t]},{v[t],e[t],0},{v[t],0,k[t]},{0,\
e[t],k[t]}},{t,-10,40},PlotStyle->{Thick,Dashed,Dashed,Dashed},\
BoxRatios->Automatic,PlotRange->All] *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I made a little mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

Very good. Syntax error:  need x[t]^2 construct and not x^2[t].  Also, I used below the `NDSolveValue` function which returns the three solutions in an array as {xF,yF,zF} but need to specify {x,y,z} as the functions in the call.  Then use `ParametricPlot3D to plot the phase diagram.  Added an arrow to show directions, axes labels and title:

```
 \[Eta] = 0.75;
\[Delta] = 0.1;
\[Tau] = 25.4;
m1 = 5;
m2 = 0.0001;
a = 0.1;
b = 0.85;
P = 25;
c = 1;
r = 0.1;
{xF, yF, zF} = 
 NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == m1*y[t] + m2*z[t] - a*x[t]^2, 
   x[t /; t <= 0] == 1.5, 
   y'[t] == r*(P - y[t]) - b*x[t - \[Tau]] + c*\[Eta]*x[t - \[Tau]], 
   y[t /; t <= 0] == 0.5, 
   z'[t] == (1 - \[Eta])*x[t - d] - \[Delta]*z[t], 
   z[t /; t <= 0] == 1}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 40}]
aStart = {xF[39.8], yF[39.8], zF[39.8]}
aEnd = {xF[40], yF[40], zF[40]}
theArrow = Graphics3D@Arrow[{aStart, aEnd}];
pp1 = ParametricPlot3D[{xF[t], yF[t], zF[t]}, {t, 0, 40}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Style["Phase portrait of {x[t],y[t],z[t]}", 14, Bold, Black], 
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["x[t]", 14, Bold, Black], 
     Style["y[t]", 14, Bold, Black], 
     Style["z[t]", Bold, 14, Black]}];
Show[{pp1, theArrow}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was very helpful for me. :)